# How do I implement a spec for this format?

Tags: vst, kaitai-struct

I am working on the [VST3 preset format](https://developer.steinberg.help/display/VST/Preset+Format). This is what I managed till now:

```yaml
meta:
  id: vstpreset
  file-extension: vstpreset
  endian: le
seq:
  - id: magic
    contents: 'VST3'
  - id: version
    type: u4
  - id: class_id
    type: str
    size: 32
    encoding: ASCII
  - id: ofs_chunk_list
    type: u8
instances:
  chunk_list:
    pos: ofs_chunk_list
    type: chunk_list
    size-eos: true
types:
  chunk:
    seq:
      - id: blob
        size-eos: true
  chunk_list:
    seq:
      - id: magic
        contents: 'List'
      - id: len_entries
        type: u4
      - id: entries
        repeat: expr
        repeat-expr: len_entries
        type: entry
    types:
      entry:
        seq:
          - id: id
            type: u4
          - id: offset
            type: u8
          - id: length
            type: u8
        instances:
          chunk:
            io: _root._io
            pos: offset
            size: length
```

This kind of works; however, I cannot figure out how to implement the section labelled **DATA AREA** in the illustration shown in the link above. *Isn't it kinda unintuitive to store the **CHUNK LIST** after the **DATA AREA**?*

Comment: I guess you may not want to "implement" it (it is possible to create a field for it and reuse its `_io` if you want stricter bounds checking, hut it will cause memory overhead of the size of that area in the current versions of KS runtimes) at all, it seems `entry.chunk` should do the job well.